# How to graph a sin & cos wave

Tags: graphing-functions, elementary-functions

I've got a time column of numbers(x) from 0 - 20 in 0.1 intervals and i've got a sin(x) and cos(x) column. I've got to produce some kind of wave like graph from it. Although I'm not sure which numbers are supposed to go where and in what order to make the graph right. (Pretty new at this).

The question i've been given is "for each value of x, plot the curve for sin(x) and cos(x)".

So how do I go about plotting the graph? What do I need to do to the sin and cos values to get the wave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each value $x$, evaluate $y_1 = \cos x$, and plot $(x, y_1),$ and also evaluate $y_2 = \sin(x)$, and plot $(x, y_2)$.

So for example, suppose $x = 2$. Then $y_1 = \cos(2)$. And you can plot the point $(2,\cos(2))$ as a point on the graph of $f(x) = \cos x$. And then evaluate $y_2 = \sin(2).$ So you can plot the point $(2, \sin(2))$ as a point on the graph of $f(x) = \sin(x)$.

Do this for each value in the left-side column, though I'd suggest perhaps doing this first for $x = 1, x = 2, \ldots, x = 20$, so for each function $f(x) = \cos x$, $f(x) = \sin(x)$ you have 20 points to plot.  That should give you a rough sketch (connecting the dots = points) for each graph. If you want to "fine tune" your graphs any further, you can evaluate each function at values of $x$ using smaller intervals.

SUGGESTION: Do this evaluating and plotting on two separate graphs: one for the graph of $\cos x$, the other for the graph of $\sin x$, so you know which points you've plotted are points that belong to the $\cos x$ curve, and which are points belonging to the $\sin x$ curve.